# How to create a Trello card from Slack with a custom command?

Tags: trello, slack

We are using Trello as our bug tracker at my workplace. I want it to be easy to add new issues from Slack.

**The ideal:** User types in Slack: `/bug [bug title]` or `/trello bug [bug title]` and a new card is created at the end of list "Bugs" on our product board.

[The Trello App for Slack](https://help.trello.com/article/1049-slack-app) does not appear to be able to do this.

2 Problems:

- Our list "Bugs" is NOT the first list on the board. By default, the app's "create new card" command adds cards to the first list on a board. I don't believe this is configurable?
- The default Slack command to create a new card is `/trello add [card name]`. This is a bit generic. I'd hope to create a distinct command for only the `bug` workflow.

Is my ideal doable with the default Slack & Trello integration? Do I need to use a third party service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accomplished this with the third party service Zapier. Zapier lets you build a 'Zap' which is a series of actions between your connected accounts. I named mine TrelloBugBot:

[image]

The steps:

1. **Slack:** *Trigger - New Mention.* Listen for mentions of the string `trellobug`.
2. **Trello:** *Search - Find Member.* Tries to match the Slack user to an existing Trello user
3. **Formatter by Zapier:** *Action - Transform to Lowercase.* Grabs the full Slack message that contains `trellobug` and turns it into lowercase.
4. **Formatter by Zapier:** *Action - Split text.* Grabs the full Slack message that contains `trellobug` and parses out the title of the bug.
5. **Trello:** *Action - Create Card.* Makes a new card in a specified Board/List. The card is named with the parsed Slack message, the message thread is linked, and the matched user is added to the card.

Zapier is free for 2 step Zaps. To set up this Zap you'll have to pay.